# Why does shifting 24 bits result in a negative value?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

When I perform a 24 bit-shift for a number less than 256 I get a negative result? Why is that?

```js
console.log( (200<<23)>>23 );

console.log( (200<<24)>>24 ); // ???
```

Comment: `console.log( (200<<24) >>> 24);` use the right operators to get the right answers ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since bit shifts work in binary, let's look at the binary representation. 32 bits are used for those operators.

```
Decimal    | Binary
200        | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 1000
```

Now shift left 24 places...

```
200        | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 1000
-939524096 | 1100 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Most importantly, notice how the first bit is now a `1`, which indicates a negative number in signed 32-bit numbers.

The next thing to note is that `>>` is a *sign-propagating* right shift. This means that when you shift right again, you are shifting in copies of the first bit.

```
-939524096 | 1100 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
-56        | 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 1000
```

However if you use `>>>` instead, you get a zero-fill right shift. As the name implies, it always shifts in `0`s.

```
-939524096 | 1100 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
200        | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 1000
```